# Google Optimize experiment not showing data from GA4 server-side

Tags: optimization, server-side, google-analytics-4

I've been using Optimize on my site successfully for over a year. I'm transitioning to our new GA4 container. I understand the GA4 connection is in beta and will be deprecated. My understanding is it should still work till Sept 2023. We've successfully run two experiences previously in the GA4 container.

I have two tests that have been running from more than 2 days. The test variants are being applied to my website. However, no impressions are being recorded or shown in the "Reporting" tab for the experience. I don't see why that would be the case.

[Screenshot of experiment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARP9Z.png)

Optimize shows that it is properly installed when I click "Check Installation." We've installed Optimize through GTM.

We have a standard server-side tagging setup for GA4. The Optimize tag is set to fire before the GA4 configuration tag.

I expected experiment impressions would be recorded as usual the experiment "Reporting" page on Optimize.

I tried the Optimize installation troubleshooter. The experiments are running properly in my Universal Analytics Optimize container. I checked GTM and the Optimize tag is firing properly.

Can you help troubleshooting this?

Comment: Any success on fixing this? I'm having a similar issue. I'm seeing "experiment_impression" in GA4 in Analytics. But the data never show up in Optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into similar issues trying to get a server-side experiment up and running in Google Optimize according this guide from Google: https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments?technology=ga4.

I am generating `experiment_impression` events with `experiment_id` and `variant_id` parameters for GA4. Google Optimize seems to record the fact that there are sessions in the experiment, but other than that it simply doesn't report anything. I am under the impression that the GA4 + Google Optimize connection is fundamentally broken (at least for server-side) and I don't expect that it will get fixed, since Google will sunset Google Optimize.